# Bash : sed -n arguments

Tags: bash, algorithm

While reading results of a ls instance, I'm trying to display a specific term from a specific line using sed :

Here is what I managed to do until now :

```
echo $(ls -lAtro | sed -n '3p' | cut -d' ' -f 6 )
```

This is reading the 6th term of the 3rd line. What I'm trying to do is replace the '3p' by a more simple variable which would permit to do something like this :

```
linetoread=3
echo $(ls -lAtro | sed -n "$linetoread" | cut -d' ' -f 6 )
```

The above example doesn't work of course, but you get the idea. What can I do to achieve this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"$linetoread"` --> `"${linetoread}p"`.

Comment: `echo $(command)` is the same as `command`, by the way. And secondly, the [output of `ls` isn't meant for parsing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Thank you for you answer John. This is what I tried but it displays nothing, so I guess it's incorrect.

Comment: Benjamin : I know ls isn't meant for parsing, but I have no choice in this particular case.

Comment: `"${linetoread}p"` should work. Did you try that code in a simple test case as you have shown in your Q, or plug into a `while` loop or other shell construct?  Use `set -vx` to turn on shell debug/trace so you can see how your env-vars are being interpreted. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try `awk` instead-

```
line=3 ; 
ls -lAtro | awk -v var="$line" 'NR==var {print $6}'
```

This takes the variable `line=3` and feeds it into `awk` (the `awk -v` part).

The `NR==var` ensures that you get the line corresponding to your variable.

Then you can change the `print $6` part to match whichever column you want. Note that the default delimiter is a space.

Of course, as pointed out in the comments, you shouldn't be parsing the output of `ls`.